# How to use setChecked method in the following code

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I have this code

```
Switch serviceSwitch;
serviceSwitch =(Switch) this.findViewById(R.id.switchservice);
serviceSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
{

    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) 
    {


        if(isChecked)
        {
            arrayChecking();
            serviceSwitch.setChecked(false);             
        }
    }
}

 public void arrayChecking()
{

    if(tbPreferenceArray.length>0)
    {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Set the Time and Day", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



        }
    else
    {
         Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TimerService.class);
         MainActivity.this.startService(i);
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
    }
}
```

From the code, when the user turned on the switch the method call for `arrayChecking()` will execute and also there is the code to reset the switch to (false), but this code is not working, `serviceSwitch.setChecked (false);` is not working. Can anybody help me to solve this simple issue?? Sorry for the language

Comment: By "not working", do you mean the code crash?

Comment: No, there is no any code crash...I mean the switch is not setting to false(switch off state).

Comment: Hi,frnds can anybody help me plz??

Comment: Show the code for `arrayChecking();
`

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `arrayChecking` method a little bit:

```
public void arrayChecking(){
    if(tbPreferenceArray.length>0){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Set the Time and Day", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //Add this to set the Switch checked to false
        serviceSwitch.setChecked(false); 
    }
    else{
         Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TimerService.class);
         MainActivity.this.startService(i);
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
    }
}
```

And remove the `serviceSwitch.setChecked(false);` from your `onCheckedChanged` method:

```
serviceSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) 
    {
        if(isChecked)
        {
            arrayChecking();             
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi actually wht i need is.. i have a switch in the app ,so i want to on the switch only when the tbPreferenceArray(Its an array to store toggle button states)is filled with some values...If the array is empty i need to reset the switch to false.when a user cliks on the switch the app will check the array is empty or not? if the array is empty the app must turn off the switch and give a tost to set date n time

Comment: Hi ,marcus ..it caught an exception at the time of method call(arrayChecking();).Tried hard,Dnt knw how to deals wth it ,can u help me plz??

Comment: 02-18 16:08:26.828: E/switchfailed(10816): java.lang.NullPointerException